# C++ operator precedence

Tags: c++, operators, operator-precedence

Lets say we have an iterator (iter) over a list of pointers to memory assigned to heap space, if I do that

```
delete (*iter++)
```

am I right that the precedence is first dereference iterator to get memory address then free the space and then increment the iterator to free the next element ?

Comment: Do not write code that requires too much though to figure out what is going on - better to spread it over a few lines. That way you will prevent errors either now or in the future.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what is going on behind the scenes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect is as you write, but it's achieved using a slightly different sequence:

1. The post-increment has highest precedence, so it's evaluated first. However, its return value (which is processed by further operators) is the value of `iter` **before** the increment.
2. Dereference is evaluated next, returning pointer to which the non-incremented value of `iter` was "pointing."
3. `delete` is evaluated last, and the pointer is deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Although [`++` has higher precedence than `*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the side effects of post-increment `++` are applied *after* the dereference operator `*` has used the iterator's value. That is the behavior of the post-increment, or suffix `++`, (as opposed to the pre-increment, or prefix `++`). This rule applies to iterators as well as the "plain" pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The *precedence* is actually the reverse, and if the iterator is of class type (with overloaded operators) this is the order of calls to the operator functions:

- The increment operator is called to increment the iterator. It returns a copy of itself **before** the increment.
- The dereference operator is called on the temporary iterator and returns the value of the list item to which `iter` used to call.
- The pointer just returned is deleted, i.e. the pointed-to object is destructed and then the memory freed.

Answer (score 0):

The line is equivalent to this:

```
delete (*(iter++))
```

But since postfix increment returns the original value, you are still dereferencing the original value of `iter`. Therefore, if `iter` points at a pointer to a dynamically allocated object, the `delete` will destroy that object. Then `iter` will be left pointing to the next pointer along.