# Precedence of dereference and postfix

Tags: c, operators, operator-precedence

When I read the TCPL by K&R, I just couldn't understand two expressions:

```
*p++ = val;  /*push val onto stack */
```

Here is my idea:

- dereference and postfix has the same precedence, and associativity is right to left,so

  `*p++ = val`   maybe the same with `*(p++) = val`, because the pointer usually is the  next position to the top , so in this code, p increase 1 first because of the parenthesis, so the p is the two units above the current top ,but not the one unit above the current top ,where the val should be!!! Thx

Comment: Post-fix operator has higher precedence than dereference `*`, so it is exec first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence And `p++` will return the current value for dereference, not the incremented value.

Comment: in short, `*p++ = val` means: 1) set the variable referenced by `p` to the value `val` 2) then increment the pointer `p`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The prefix increment/decrement and dereference operators are equal precedence, but the postfix operator is higher,  so `*p++` is the same as `*(p++)`, which is like writing `*p = val; p++;`

If you wrote `(*p)++ = val`, it wouldn't compile, as you'd be trying to assign a value to a number.

Comment: But the p++ maybe exec first because of the parenthesis,so the p++ should before the dereference. Isn't it?

Comment: @wwwjieo0, the `++` *does* go first.  But since it's a *post-increment* operator, its return value is `p` *before* incrementing.

Comment: @CarlNorum  I see, 3 things happend in order: 1.dereference 2.copy assignment 3.increase.  Thx

Comment: @wwwjieo0: `p` doesn't get incremented until "later" - that means at the latest before the next statement, but not within the same expression like this.

Answer (score 4):

Precedence and Associativity of Operators in K&R, table 2-1, pg 53, 
isn't as granular and complete as more recent table in Stroustrup, tC++PL,Sed, sec 6.2 Operator summary, p120-121.

[C++ operator precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295226/c-operator-precedence?rq=1)
Agnew's answer is excellent.

he points out association is indeed R->L for unary operators and that for *(p++),

1. first p++ evaluates, but the previous p value is **returned**
2. then *p is evaluated with this previous p value and the assignment occurs
3. then the statement ends and p++ post increment value is now active, ie pointer p is now bumped.

Answer (score 1):

Precedence of operators is an order of their interpretation by compiler, not the order of their execution.

Operator precedence actually means "where to put parentheses". Hence you are correct that `*p++` is the same as `*(p++)`. 
But now we need to understand what is `*(p++)`. It means taking `*p` and then increasing `p++`, because of post-fixed operation.

So, in short, you just mixed order of interpretation by compiler (which is determined by parentheses or precedence) and order of execution (which is determined by post- or pre-fixed definition).