# Operator precedence of postfix increment

Tags: c++, c, operator-precedence

I made a silly mistake of doing *p++; thinking that p would be dereferenced first and then the value pointed by p would get incremented. So I found that this is more akin to:

*(p++);

Because the postfix ++ increment operator has higher precedence than the * dereference operator.

But now that I'm thinking in terms of operator precedence, I find that postfix++ is higher than for example the equality == operator, but in:

```
int a = 0;
if (0 == a++) // Condition is true
```

And the same goes for ! logical NOT:

```
int a = 0;
if (!a++) // Condition is true, a is incremented after the condition check
          // even if it's higher precedence than !
```

So there must be more to it from what I've seen.

I've heard about the right-to-left and clockwise/spiral rule, but every time I've tried to grasp it it escaped my understanding.

I don't want a full explanation on the evaluation order, as I can struggle through that with my own reading. But am I at least right that it's not just a matter of operator precedence? For example the answer that *p++ is evaluated the way it is because the postfix++ operator is of higher precedence is only half right or part of the answer?

[Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15345591/4696802)

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255147/does-p-increment-after-dereferencing

Comment: Postfix `++` increments the variable, but returns the old value. That's the whole point of postfix `++`.

Comment: "Precedence" in C and C++ is lexical. "Executed before" is not something you should consult a precedence table for.

Comment: "Operator precedence" and "order of evaluation" are completely different things.

Comment: As @n.m. said, precedence and order are different things. Precedence defines that in `f(1)+g(2)*h(7)` the value returned from `f()` call will be added to a product of values of `g()` and `h()`, while order of evaluation defines (or sometimes does not) which of `f()`, `g()` and `h()` can be executed first and which last.

Comment: It's called *post increment* (`p++`) because the increment happens (notionally) *after* the value is taken. This is as opposed to *pre increment* (`++p`) where the increment happens *before* the value is taken.

Comment: Then that answer when it says that it's evaluated that way because postfix++ operator is higher precedence than the dereference operator is only half right then, that's what I'm asking. As precedence isn't the sole factor.

Comment: @Zebra - It's a good idea to avoid mixing increments/decrements with other sub-expressions. Otherwise you sooner or later end up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior-in-c). `if (!a++)` is just *hard to read* code for no particular reason. "Being too smart is not smart"(TM).

Answer (score 2):

Your claim, *Condition is true, `a` is incremented after the condition check even if it's higher precedence than `!`*, is wrong.
It is not necessary that `a` will be incremented after the condition check. It can happen anytime. The only certainty is that in expression `!a++`, old value of `a` will be used for `!` operator.
Operator precedence will help in grouping operands. Operand in `!a++` will be grouped as `! (a++)`. This grouping doesn't mean that `a` will be incremented before `!` operator is applied to the result fo `a++`.

Answer (score 1):

`p++` means increment p and return it's original value, it has to be evaluated before any other operator that uses its value. If you think of increment as a function it might be easier to understand:

```
int inc(int& v)
{
  int value = v;
  v++;
  return value;
}

int a = 0;
if (inc(a) == 0)
```

Comment: *"it has to be evaluated before any other operator that uses its value"* - Can you clarify what you mean by that? What are you bundling with "evaluation"?

Comment: @StoryTeller by evaluation I mean executing a statement and determining its value?

Comment: There's no statement, only an expression with side effects. If you are implying the side effects are somehow also part of an "atomic" evaluation, your answer is wrong.